# Sitecore: Experience Editor broken after upgrading from sitecore 7 to sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, upgrade, sitecore7, sitecore8

I have upgraded to sitecore 8 and facing critical issues regarding only the Experience Editor.

After logging into Experience editor with Admin rights, the page opens only with one tab "Optimization"; no buttons are active though.

Also, i found one issue that i was familiar with:clicking any web edit button would add a "#" symbol at the end of the url. This  behavior was found when i was developing a javascript and debugging it and whenever there would be any error in js, "#" would get suffixed to url and button click wouldnt work.

I am not sure if this related to SPEAK features and how to tackle this issue with Experience Editor ?!

Comment: Just as a starting point for investigation: if you have a sample page that comes with Sitecore 8 (or you create a simple page separate from your solution and do not mess with your custom code) - does not it work in Experience Editor as well?

Comment: Hi Martin. Pages display properly in the editor but the ribbon tabs are not displayed. Also the same for simple page.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in past. Ensure you have got **webedit.css** file at the web root. Looking at your description above I guess that is exact case.

Comment: I had a look and found the webedit.css in the web root. Also other webedit files (dialog,ribbon and fix) are also present at "\shell\Applications\WebEdit"